# Show that $f(x)$ cannot be zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable everywhere, $f’(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(0) = 1$ then show that $f(x)$ cannot be zero for any $x$.

I can see that this will not be the case for at least $x$ strictly greater than zero. I can also see that if $f$ is zero for some $x <0$ then we can’t have $f(0) = 1$ but I don’t know how to formally prove the proposition. Please help me out.

Comment: Presumably you don't just want to prove that $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: No that is not what I want I want to prove.

Comment: With $g(x)=f(x)\,e^{-x}$, you'll have $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$, i.e. $g(x)=g(0)=1$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector that is very elegant, but is there a way to do it without using the exponential function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $g(t)=f(t)f(-t)$. Then $g'(t)=f(t)f(-t)-f(t)f(-t)=0$, and so, since $g(0)=1$, $(\forall t\in\Bbb R):f(t)f(-t)=1$. So, $f$ has no zeros.

Comment: Works both forward and backward in time, great! :)

Answer (score 5):

$f'(x)=f(x)$ implies $f'(x)f(x)=f^2(x)$, so $$f^2(x)=f^2(0)+\int^x_0 2f'(t)f(t)\,dt=f^2(0)+2\int^x_0 f^2(t)\,dt\ge f^2(0)=1$$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: (+1) Very elegant!